# How to get keyboard layout (language) in terminal (console, command-line)

Tags: command-line, keyboard-layout

Is it possible and how to reliably gather the current keyboard language and/or layout via command-line in Ubuntu?

We've already tried different options:

1. `localectl` (`status`);
2. `cat /etc/default/locale`;
3. `cat /etc/default/keyboard`;
4. `setxkbmap -query`;
5. `gsettings ...`;
6. `setxkbmap -print | grep xkb_symbols` (`setxkbmap -v | awk -F "+" '/symbols/ {print $2}'`);
7. Tried to install `xkblayout-state`, but `make` failed on fresh OS install - skipped.

All of these output the same per each command with keyboard layout change - **us** layout.

`uname -a` shows `Linux x4 4.4.0-97-generic #120-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 19 17:28:18 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

The current distribution is `KDE Neon 5.8` (based on Ubuntu) and window system is `X11`.

---

The outputs of the above commands:

`$ localectl status`:

```
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   LC_NUMERIC=lt_LT.UTF-8
   LC_TIME=lt_LT.UTF-8
   LC_MONETARY=lt_LT.UTF-8
   LC_PAPER=lt_LT.UTF-8
   LC_NAME=lt_LT.UTF-8
   LC_ADDRESS=lt_LT.UTF-8
   LC_TELEPHONE=lt_LT.UTF-8
   LC_MEASUREMENT=lt_LT.UTF-8
   LC_IDENTIFICATION=lt_LT.UTF-8
 VC Keymap: n/a
X11 Layout: us
X11 Model: pc105
```

`$ cat /etc/default/locale`:

```
#  File generated by update-locale                                                                                                                                                 
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"                                                                                                                                                                 
LC_NUMERIC="lt_LT.UTF-8"                                                                                                                                                           
LC_TIME="lt_LT.UTF-8"                                                                                                                                                              
LC_MONETARY="lt_LT.UTF-8"                                                                                                                                                          
LC_PAPER="lt_LT.UTF-8"                                                                                                                                                             
LC_NAME="lt_LT.UTF-8"                                                                                                                                                              
LC_ADDRESS="lt_LT.UTF-8"                                                                                                                                                           
LC_TELEPHONE="lt_LT.UTF-8"                                                                                                                                                         
LC_MEASUREMENT="lt_LT.UTF-8"                                                                                                                                                       
LC_IDENTIFICATION="lt_LT.UTF-8"
```

`$ cat /etc/default/keyboard`:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE                                                                                                                                                      

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

`$ setxkbmap -query`:

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc101
layout:     us,lt
options:    grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

`$ setxkbmap -print | grep xkb_symbols`:

```
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+lt:2+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)"        };
```

`$ setxkbmap -v | awk -F "+" '/symbols/ {print $2}'`:

```
us
```

`$ cat ~/.config/kxkbrc`:

```
[Layout]
DisplayNames=,
LayoutList=us,lt
LayoutLoopCount=-1
Model=pc101
Options=grp:alt_shift_toggle
ResetOldOptions=true
ShowFlag=false
ShowLabel=true
ShowLayoutIndicator=true
ShowSingle=false
SwitchMode=Global
Use=true
```

All of these commands were executed two times (before and after keyboard language/layout change) - no useful enough output.

---

However:

`$ xset -q | grep -A 0 'LED' | cut -c59-67` (English language is enabled):

```
00000000
```

`$ xset -q | grep -A 0 'LED' | cut -c59-67` (Lithuanian language is enabled):

```
00001000
```

Considering it's changing, is it a correct and reliable option?

Answer (score 7):

As regards **Ubuntu 17.10**, I just figured out that the current keyboard layout in a desktop session is saved differently.

I have a Swedish and English (US) layout available. Previously I could do:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
[('xkb', 'se'), ('xkb', 'us')]
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current
uint32 0
```

The *current* value 0 (zero) told me that the current layout was the first layout in the *sources* list. However, in 17.10 the *current* value is not altered if I switch layout.

Instead, 17.10 includes the *mru-sources* key, which lists the **m**ost **r**ecently **u**sed input sources. Hence, when Swedish is my current layout, it looks like this:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources
[('xkb', 'se'), ('xkb', 'us')]
```

and if I switch to English it looks like this:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources
[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'se')]
```

So the current layout is simply the first input source in the *mru-sources* list.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources` gives `No such key 'mru-sources'`

Comment: @V.7: It may well be a GNOME specific thing. Ubuntu uses GNOME by default in 17.10.

Comment: I don't use Gnome. KDE Plasma instead.

Comment: @V.7: I know, so I suspected that this wouldn't help you. Found it still motivated to document my 'finding'.

Comment: Btw Thank you very much as needed @Gunnar Hjalamarsson :)