# keyboard shortcut for toggling keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have Ubuntu 18. Before upgrading, I had set up shortcuts for toggling keyboards following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201677/switch-to-specific-keyboard-layout-using-ctrlshiftnum/984981#984981) in Ubuntu 16, but the command no longer works.

Could anyone help me? I wasn't able to find the command for Ubuntu 18.

Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/973329) provides a hint, but not a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it didn't work...

Comment: I have seen a solution at Ask Ubuntu, but unfortunately I can't find it now...